# Can't use orderby in WP_Query

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query

I can't get my posts to order by the date, descading. I've got the following code:

```
$jobs = new WP_Query(array(
    'posts_per_page' => 50,
    'post_type' => 'job',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'cache_results' => false
));
```

And this is the output of `$jobs->request`:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'job' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) AND post_date >= "2014-09-10"   LIMIT 0, 50
```

Somehow the whole ordering section is missing, and there's 3 spaces instead. What happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `orderby` parameter value should be `date` and not `post_date`. Have a look at the orderby and order parameters in [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

I know the was a track ticket out about this subject, just can't remember where, but yes, I do agree that the value should be `post_date` and not `date`